# How to notify classes higher in the hierarchy for changes?

Tags: design-patterns, circular-dependency

Let's assume I have two classes based on composition:

Class A which holds a reference to Class B.

Now B shouldn't know anything about his A but needs to notify A to make an update on certain events. What needs to be updated is an object that A holds. I'm wondering how to solve this in a clean way.

**Solution one:**
A observes if an event occurs on B and makes the update on the object.

**Solution two:**
A injects the object in the constructor of B. The latter handles the update.

**Solution three:**
Adapter class where B is a registered publisher and A the subscriber that receives the messages of the publisher.

Which of these do you think is the better solution? Is there a better way which I haven't mentioned yet?

Comment: This is very much opinion based, but I'd go with option 2 (with an (optionally null) object exposing the updated() method). B does not need to know how the update takes place. Neither A nor B need to know too much about each other.

Comment: @LSerni thats unfortunate : ( any idea how I can improve the question?

Comment: I think that depending on circumstances, all three solutions might have something to say for them. It's also very possible that my preference stems just from my own, skewed, experience. I see for example you got an answer suggesting option #3. Perhaps this would be more on topic on Software Engineering? (I'm not sure)

Comment: @LSerni I see there is https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution one and three are more suitable in context where B may publish events to multiple clients.
In your case, it doesn't seem to be the case.
Using a event facility for a communication only designed between the composed and the composer seems not relevant.

> Solution two: A injects the object in the constructor of B. The latter
>   handles the update.

It seems the finest way.
In fact, you could pass `A` in the `B` constructor where the `B` constructor accepts a specific interface that provides "callback" methods to communicate with `A`.

For example :

```
public interface CallBackA {
   void updateFoo(int value);
}

public class A implements CallBackA{

    public A() {
        new B(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateFoo((int value) { 
         ...
    }
}

public class B {

    private CallBackA callBackA;

    public B(CallBackA callBackA) {
        this.callBackA = callBackA;
    }

    public void foo() {
        int updatedValue = 123;
        callBackA.updateFoo(updatedValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: Now what if I have composition with a deeper hierarchy: Such as A->B->C->D. Now if D changes state it needs to send the information to C, B and A. Basically bubble up information without knowing about these higher classes. Wouldnt some sort of "Mediator" fit there? Say I initialize the Mediator in A. I subscribe A as a receiver and pass the Mediator to B where I do the same thing and all the way down to D. D wont be a receiver though but a registered "sender". When something happens it calls "Mediator.Notify()" and A, B and C know what to do.

Comment: In this case,  Observable/event patterns makes indeed more sense. About your scenario, yes you could do it  but it seems too complex for the need. If you want that D may notify A, you could make D an Observable and A an Observer and register in a D instance a A instance.

Answer (score 0):

See the observer design pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern